# imageSegmentationResult.original return null in android 12 - huawei image segmentation

Tags: android, image, image-segmentation

I'm using huawei image segmentation for background remove from the image. this code work perfectly fine up to android 11 but it get crash on android 12.

**Code:**

```
private final void analyse(Bitmap bitmap) {

    pd = new ProgressDialog(this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
    pd.setMessage("Process");
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    pd.setCancelable(false);
    pd.show();
    MLFrame mlFrame = MLFrame.fromBitmap(bitmap);

    mAnalyzer.asyncAnalyseFrame(mlFrame)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<MLImageSegmentation>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(MLImageSegmentation mlImageSegmentation) {

                    addSelectedBackground(mlImageSegmentation);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Exception e) {

        }
    });
}

private void addSelectedBackground(MLImageSegmentation mlImageSegmentation) {

    mutableBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            mlImageSegmentation.original.getWidth(),
            mlImageSegmentation.original.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    );
    pd.dismiss();
    if (maskBitmap != null) {
        maskBitmap.recycle();
        maskBitmap = null;
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mlImageSegmentation.foreground, 0F, 0F, null);
    maskBitmap = mutableBitmap;
    call();
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.5.2.300'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-segmentation:2.1.0.301'
implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-vision-image-segmentation-body-model:2.2.0.300'
```

Comment: Hi @Ryan M
could you be able to publish your app on google play store with these sdk's ?

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan I have no idea.  I just edited the question's formatting.

Comment: @ helly is your app is live on play store with these sdk's ?

Comment: Not made app for play store